# Amex cc questions

Tags: credit-card

If I am issued a new card due to a lost or stolen card with American Express Platinum Card will the first 10 numbers of the account number stay the same and only the last five change or do they still use the first set of 10 numbers

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you can be sure of is that the new number will be issued within American Express's [BIN range](https://www.bincodes.com/bin-list/).  That is, it will start with a 34 or a 37, and have 15 digits.

Beyond that, it's entirely up to AmEx what they do with their cards.  *Generally*, all cards of a given type will share their first six digits (the full BIN), or a small range of BINs, but not always.